# Problem solving, radio buttons adding values on textbox. Improving solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have a series of radio buttons (rdoGroup1,rdoGroup2,rdoGroup3) and three textboxes at the end of the table which each textbox txtTotalC will count the amount of radio buttons with C value have been selected, txtTotalB will count the amount of radio buttons with B value,  txtTotalA will count the amount of radio buttons with A value.

At the moment I could only workout a standar javascript function (see code at the bottom) which it will get very big as I have 11 radio groups and I am treating each one separate.

I was wondering if there is any quickest way to do this on jquery.

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td><input type="radio" name="rdoGroup1" value="C"/></td>
     <td><input type="radio" name="rdoGroup1" value="B"/></td>
     <td><input type="radio" name="rdoGroup1" value="A"/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><input type="radio" name="rdoGroup2" value="C"/></td>
     <td><input type="radio" name="rdoGroup2" value="B"/></td>
     <td><input type="radio" name="rdoGroup2" value="A"/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><input type="radio" name="rdoGroup3" value="C"/></td>
     <td><input type="radio" name="rdoGroup3" value="B"/></td>
     <td><input type="radio" name="rdoGroup3" value="A"/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><input type="text" id="txtTotalC"></td>
     <td><input type="text" id="txtTotalB"></td>
     <td><input type="text" id="txtTotalA"></td>
   </tr>
</table>


var rdoGroup1A, rdoGroup1B, rdoGroup1C = 0;
function radioGroupSelected(rdoControl) {

    if (rdoControl.name == "rdoGroup1") {

        if (rdoControl.checked.value == "C") {
            txtTotalC.value = txtTotalC.value + 1;
                if (rdoGroup1B== 1) {
                    rdoGroup1B-= 1;
                }
                if (rdoGroup1A== 1) {
                    rdoGroup1A -= 1;
                }
            rdoGroup1C += 1;
        }
        if (rdoControl.checked.value == "B") {
            txtTotalB.value = txtTotalB.value + 1;
                if (rdoGroup1C== 1) {
                    rdoGroup1C -= 1;
                }
                if (rdoGroup1A == 1) {
                    rdoGroup1A -= 1;
                }
            rdoGroup1B += 1;
        }
        if (rdoControl.checked.value == "A") {
            txtTotalA.value = txtTotalB.value + 1;
                if (rdoGroup1B == 1) {
                    rdoGroup1B -= 1;
                }
                if (rdoGroup1C == 1) {
                    rdoGroup1C -= 1;
                }
            rdoGroup1A += 1;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$("table").delegate(":radio", "change", function() {
    var radios = $(this).closest("table").find(":radio:checked");
    $.each(["A", "B", "C"], function(i, l) {
      $("#txtTotal" + l).val(radios.filter("[value='"+l+"']").length);
    });
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/AHEs5/1/). The basic approach is that instead of keeping up with values, just total them up each time, keeping things *much* simpler.

How the above works:

- Attach a single event handler for all radio buttons in the `<table>` via [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)
- When any radio button changes:

  - Get all currently checked radio buttons
  - Loop through whatever possible values there are ("A", "B", "C", an array above)...or you could unfold it into 3 lines, the [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) just makes it easier to expand later).
  - For each possible value, set it's total box value, e.g. `#txtTotalA` for the first, to the [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) (number of elements) matched by using [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to get the ones that are checked, with that value.

If you have multiple tables, you can still use the above, just change the total boxes with IDs to classes, and find them that way, for example you'd use `$(this).closest("table").find(".txtTotal"+l)` instead of `$("#txtTotal" + l)` (caching the `$(this).closest("table")` for speed would help).

Comment: +1 Beat me to it! Though mine wasn't quite so elegant, that **is** nice.

Comment: Nick Craver: Wow, I would give you + 1000 if I could, I really appreciate the explanation you give as it is quite advance function for me. Thanks a lot. +1.

Comment: @Starter - welcome :) let me know if there's any portion you'd like a better explanation on :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would like to know when you say function (i,l) What is l?. Once again, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Starter - in a [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) loop, the callback (that `function`) gets 2 arguments, the index in the array, and the element, so the first time it's `being called with `0`, `"A"`...the second `1`,`"B"`, etc :)